# How to draw a list of sprites in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am asking if it is possible to draw a list of sprites in Pygame, and if so how?

I am attempting to draw from a two dimensional list, that will draw the map

import pygame

```
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)


screen_width = 700
screen_height = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])


pygame.init()

image = pygame.image.load("Textures(Final)\Grass_Tile.bmp").convert()
imagerect = image.get_rect()

tilemap = [
          [image, image, image],
          [image, image, image]
        ]


done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()



while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    screen.blit(tilemap, imagerect)    

    clock.tick(20)

    pygame.display.flip()


pygame.quit()
```

I know I can do something much simpler, like drawing each image. But, I am wondering if I can do this,  so in the future when I have more sprites I can just add to the list, and create the map.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is quite possible as you describe it, but if these images aren't going to change often I would suggest pre-blitting all your map images to a pygame Surface which can later be used, using something like:

```
map_surface = pygame.Surface(( len(tilemap[0])*TILE_WIDTH, len(tilemap)*TILE_HEIGHT ))
for y,row in enumerate(tilemap):
    for x,tile_surface in enumerate(row):
        map_surface.blit(tile_surface,(x*TILE_WIDTH,y*TILE_HEIGHT))
```

and then later you can simply use:

```
screen.blit(map_surface)
```

One thing to note is that even if your map does change, you will only have to blit the changed tiles onto the `map_surface` surface, and not have to recreate the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you for that, it worked as I wanted. And yea, this map is static with a camera going to move around the map. Thank you, again!